# Parsing the Google Reader export

Tags: php, rss, simplexml

I am attempting to use SimpleXML to parse the xml file that is produced from the Google Reader export.

File example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<opml version="1.0">
    <head>
        <title>TheTechBox subscriptions in Google Reader</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <outline text="Engadget RSS Feed" title="Engadget RSS Feed"
            type="rss" xmlUrl="http://www.engadget.com/rss.xml" htmlUrl="http://www.engadget.com"/>
        <outline text="xkcd.com" title="xkcd.com" type="rss"
            xmlUrl="http://xkcd.com/rss.xml" htmlUrl="http://xkcd.com/"/>
    </body>
</opml>
```

This is what I have tried so far, the user uploads the file to this form and the form needs to loop through and extract the data.

```
<?php
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
{
    echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
}
else
{

    $import = new SimpleXMLElement($_FILES["file"]["name"]);

    foreach($import->opml->body->outline[0] as $feed){
        echo $feed["title"];
    }

}
?>
```

Right now chrome produces a server error which indicates something is very wrong on the page, the file uploads OK so it appears to be the simpleXML part.

I am planning to do something more complex with the data later, I am currently trying to get it just to echo the data on the page (for demo purposes).

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

**Here is the working code in the end**

```
$import = simplexml_load_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);

foreach($import->body->outline as $feed){
    echo $feed["title"];
}
```

This will need adding to to parse all of the data but this works.

Comment: What type of error do you get? A 500 one? And have you tried outputting the contents of `$_FILES["file"]["name"]` to ensure it's valid?

Comment: `simplexml_load_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);`

Comment: @TomWalters Yeah it's a 500 error and yes the file should be valid as I tried just echoing the basic file data out onto the page before and it worked.

Comment: @Wrikken I just tried a file_exists with the simplexml_load_file and then printed the result out on the screen and it printed the file out fine as a SimpleXMLElement Object. Do I then just loop through this loaded file as I have above?

Comment: PHP will generally only issue a 500 error in conjunction with raising a Fatal Error. You need to find or configure your log file, or (*temporarily*) `ini_set('display_errors', true); error_reporting(E_ALL);` to see what the error is.

Comment: OTOH, I think I see the bug. I'll post it as an Answer.

Comment: @IMSoP I seem to have fixed the 500 error by deleting the loop and then using a test simplexml_load_file which worked. So by the sounds of it is the loop that was/is at fault here.

Comment: Don't guess, debug! If PHP is giving you an error, find out what the error is, don't just delete some code and see if it goes away.

Comment: Ah, that, skip the `->opml->` part, `opml` is your root element (`==$import` if you will), so you don't need to address that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've fallen into a classic trap when using SimpleXML: the first object you get when parsing a file or string is not an abstract "document" object, but the parent node. In this case, the parent node is `<opml> ... </opml>`, so `$import` in your sample code is that `<opml>` node. In other words, rather than `$import->opml->body` you just need to say `$import->body`.

There's another bug in your loop as well, which is that you are asking for the first `<outline>` element (`->outline[0]`) when what you want is to be looping over *all* of the elements (`foreach( $whatever->outline as $feed )`).

Comment: Bingo! Removing the [0] now means it loops through all and removing the opml part works. I will add the working code on to the end of the question.